# Passing arguments that are just getting created

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, anonymous-function

I am making a NodeJS/Express listener and have inputs which are being created as my `connectListener` is being made:

```
app.get('/server/:args', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
   // ... 
   var args = req.param("args");
   var client = net.connect({port : 50505}, connectListener(args, client));
});
```

Then I have my `connectListener` function:

```
function connectListener(args, client) {
    console.log("Connected to server.");
    console.log(args);
    client.write(args);
    // .... 
}
```

However, I get an error that the arguments are undefined:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
    at connectListener (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\index.js:39:8)
    at C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\index.js:33:43
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at next (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:81:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:235:24
    at param (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:332:14)
    at param (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:348:14)
    at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:392:3)
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:313:13)
    at SendStream.send (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:494:17)
    at onstat (C:\Users\ES\workspace_luna\WptHash\server-src\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:585:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
```

So, how do I properly create the `client` variable such that it can be used in the below function? The reason I am making the function `connectListener` like this instead of inline is I plan to replicate the client across more ports to handle simultaneous connections so I don't want to re-use code nor use a global set of client variables/array (though I suppose I could...)

Comment: why are you calling the function in `net.connect({port : 50505}, connectListener(args, client));` instead of passing it as `net.connect({port : 50505}, connectListener);`? The API for `net.connect` should simply call it with the relevant arguments so that inside your function the `args` and `client` variables have meaning.

Comment: Which arguments does `connectListener` naturally accept then?

Comment: no you're missing the point. You're *calling* the function, instead of passing it as the callback function. So you're calling `net.connect({port : 50505}, <result of calling connectListener with nonexistent arguments>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is you are calling `connectListener` where you should just be setting it as the function to be called on a connect event:

`var client = net.connect({port : 50505}, connectListener);`

If you want to write to a specific client with specific args, you can do so by defining the response in your connectListener function:

```
app.get('/server/:args', function (req, res) {
    var client, args;

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    // ... 

   function connectListener () {
       console.log("Connected to server.");
       console.log(args);
       client.write(args);
       // .... 
   }

   args = req.param("args");
   client = net.connect({port : 50505}, connectListener);
});
```

Comment: Right but if I do that, how do I tell `connectListener` that it needs to look at that specific `client` and `args` variables?

Comment: Also, which higher scope variables does `connectListener` have at its disposal

Comment: You are trying to pass in a function which net.connect will call when the listener for the "connect" event is triggered.  Thus, those parameters would be passed in automatically.  If you want to overwrite them you'll need to do so in that function.